# How can I make the .active class dynamic with jquery and not just focus on the first one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using bootstrap to try to do tab-fade. That part is working. When it comes to selecting the active class I'm not able to select more than just the one. When I used my current JQuery it only makes the first element with the class of active as "hello world". I want to ultimately put the .active texts in the container on the page. How would I go about doing this? Doing this seems like it should be simple.

I've already tried putting the .active class into a variable, I've tried doing different CSS selectors, none of them worked.

```js
$('.tab-content>.active').html("Hello world");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link href="Test2.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </header>
  <nav class="nav"><span style="font-size: 30px; height: 30%">
            <ul>
              <li> <a href="#">Abab</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#">BABA</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#">CDCDC</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#">EDED</a></li>
            </ul>
          </span> </nav>
  <!--This is where jquery would interact with buttons if I need them but for this site's purposes I don't need it <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-small" id="button">Make
          text bigger</button>
          
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-small" id="button123">Make
          text smaller</button> -->

  <!--I need to use media queries with my CSS so that all of these show up or change the flex div-->

  <button id="button">Click here</button>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="Exampletabs">
    <li><a href="#Article1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Article 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Article2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Article 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Article3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Article 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Article4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Article 4</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!--Tab panes-->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="Article1"> This is a test of my typing ability. I can type pretty fast.<br>

      <p>How are you? I am doing well. I am a nouveau writer. So, don't take it personally if I suck.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="Article2"> BBBB </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="Article3"> CCC</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="Article4"> DDD</div>
  </div>


  <section id="page">
    <section id="container">

      <h1>Hello world!</h1>

      <p>Check out my skills. I have mad coding skills. I am the best. There is no one else out there like me. Any of the articles that appear in the articles section above will appear below, and, I have several pages that you can go through that all lead
        the same place. </p>

      <br>

      <p>You can click on the article sections to see different previews of my website. I hope to write many more movie reviews as time goes on. I also hope to add in some analysis about news, tech and politics. I was after all a Political Science and Communication
        major while I was in College. I can't break bad habits.</p>

    </section>
  </section>


  <p>Hello world!!!</p>
  </div>

  <ul class="pager" style="margin-right: 700px">
    <li><a href="#Article1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Article2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Article3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Article4">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Article5">5</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query selector should be `$('div.tab-content>.active').html("Hello world");`

And this should be called after updating active tab:

```js
// first time update
$('div.tab-content>.active').html("Hello world");

// update after some tab is active
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  $('div.tab-content>.active').html("Hello world");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </header>
  <nav class="nav"><span style="font-size: 30px; height: 30%">
            <ul>
              <li> <a href="#">Abab</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#">BABA</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#">CDCDC</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#">EDED</a></li>
            </ul>
          </span> </nav>
  <!--This is where jquery would interact with buttons if I need them but for this site's purposes I don't need it <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-small" id="button">Make
          text bigger</button>
          
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-small" id="button123">Make
          text smaller</button> -->

  <!--I need to use media queries with my CSS so that all of these show up or change the flex div-->

  <button id="button">Click here</button>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="Exampletabs">
    <li><a href="#Article1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Article 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Article2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Article 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Article3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Article 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Article4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Article 4</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!--Tab panes-->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="Article1"> This is a test of my typing ability. I can type pretty fast.<br>

      <p>How are you? I am doing well. I am a nouveau writer. So, don't take it personally if I suck.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="Article2"> BBBB </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="Article3"> CCC</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="Article4"> DDD</div>
  </div>


  <section id="page">
    <section id="container">

      <h1>Hello world!</h1>

      <p>Check out my skills. I have mad coding skills. I am the best. There is no one else out there like me. Any of the articles that appear in the articles section above will appear below, and, I have several pages that you can go through that all lead
        the same place. </p>

      <br>

      <p>You can click on the article sections to see different previews of my website. I hope to write many more movie reviews as time goes on. I also hope to add in some analysis about news, tech and politics. I was after all a Political Science and Communication
        major while I was in College. I can't break bad habits.</p>

    </section>
  </section>


  <p>Hello world!!!</p>
  </div>

  <ul class="pager" style="margin-right: 700px">
    <li><a href="#Article1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Article2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Article3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Article4">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Article5">5</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That got me partially to where I want to be. But, I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. I want to be able to put all of the tab panes inside the container element and then I want to be able to switch as it goes on. I realized that I made an error in attributing my #section ID and it should be container. This is my new JS code. 

var firstUpdate = $('div.tab-content>.active');

            var section = $('div.tab-content>.active');

// update after some tab is active

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {

  $("#container").html(section)

});

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution!! Sort of. Well, this is the best solution that I've come up so far. This lets me use the #container element and I realized that I can use the Jquery selector in the HTML. That saves me a lot of trouble and opens up new ways to use jQuery. :) Here you guys go. I'm so glad that I was able to find a solution here and thanks for imudin07's help!

```
$('div.tab-content>.active').html("Hello world");

// update after some tab is active
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  $("#container").html($('div.tab-content>.active'));
});
```

Now I just need to figure out how to get the code so that it resets after you click four different times. Otherwise it gets stuck at the last time.